# Ocultar pasos u omitirlo en jquery-steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

buenas a todos.

Estoy trabajando con jquery-steps, y en uno de los pasos hay dos opciones. Cuando presiono la opción A, aparece una pregunta más justo debajo. Cuando presiono la opción B, aparecen 2 preguntas en el siguiente paso.

El problema que tengo es que cuando presiono la opción A, paso por el siguiente paso en blanco. ¿Sabrían cómo ir directamente al paso final sin pasar por ese paso al presionar la opción A?

Codigo de ejemplo en [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jesusdelrioc/zLpns78c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Diculpa la demora en mi respuesta, pero aprovechando que esta misma semana respondí una pregunta respecto a este plug-in, me di a la tarea de buscar la solución a tu problema. Lo único que tenías que hacer, era agregar las condiciones que necesitabas en el evento `onStepChanged`.

Puedes ver tu código funcionando de la manera deseada en este ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block1').hide();
  $('.block2').hide();
  $('.block3').hide();
  
  $(".opcion").click(function(){
    $(".block1").show();
    $(".block2").hide();
    $(".block3").hide();
    })
    
  $(".opcion1").click(function(){
   $(".block1").hide();
   $(".block2").show();
   $(".block3").show();
   })
})

var form = $("#example-form");
form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});

form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
    if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { //priorIndex
       
       //Este código es para poder regresarte del Paso 4 al 2. Para evitar que se produzca un bucle infinito se debe agregar el return
       if (currentIndex === 2 && newIndex === 3)
           {
                $(this).steps("previous");
          return;
           }
       
       //Si el usuario en el Paso 2 selecciona la opción A, avanzará al paso 4 en lugar de al Paso 3. De lo contrario avanzará de manera normal
       if (currentIndex === 2 && $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val() == "A")
                $(this).steps("next");
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
});
```

```css
.title {
    display: none;
}

/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a {
  outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul {
  list-style: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul > li,
.tabcontrol ul > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Accessibility */

.wizard > .steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol > .steps .current-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.wizard > .content > .title,
.tabcontrol > .content > .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}


/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard > .steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.wizard > .steps .number {
  font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li {
  width: 20%;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li,
.wizard > .actions > ul > li {
  float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps > ul > li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .steps a,
.wizard > .steps a:hover,
.wizard > .steps a:active {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .steps .disabled a,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .current a,
.wizard > .steps .current a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .current a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .done a,
.wizard > .steps .done a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .done a:active {
  background: #9dc8e2;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .steps .error a,
.wizard > .steps .error a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .error a:active {
  background: #ff3111;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .content {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  min-height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard.vertical > .content {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
  width: 65%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}

.wizard > .content > .body > iframe {
  border: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input.error {
  background: rgb(251, 227, 228);
  border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
  color: #8a1f11;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.wizard > .content > .body label.error {
  color: #8a1f11;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.wizard > .actions {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul > li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions > ul > li {
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard > .actions a,
.wizard > .actions a:hover,
.wizard > .actions a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .actions .disabled a,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
}

.wizard > .loading {}

.wizard > .loading .spinner {}


/*
    Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol > .steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li:hover {
  background: #edecec;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  padding: 0 0 1px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current > a {
  padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="example-form" action="#">
    <div>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <section>
            <label for="userName">User name *</label>
            <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="password">Password *</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
            <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </section>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <section>
            <label for="name">First name *</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="surname">Last name *</label>
            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="email">Email *</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
             <div class="mobile-wrapper">
                <label for="rate" class="title mobile-block">choose an option</label>
              <div class="radio">
              <input type="radio" id="si" class="opcion" name="gender" value="A">
              <label for="si">A</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="no" class="opcion1" name="gender" value="B">
              <label for="no">B</label><br>
             </div>
             <div class="block1">
              <label for="phone">phone *</label>
              <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="required">
             </div>
            

                                    </div>
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </section>
        <h3>hol</h3>
        <section>
           <div class="block2">
              <label for="number phone">number phone *</label>
              <input id="" name="number phone" type="text" class="required">
             </div>
             <div class="block3">
              <label for="car">Car</label>
              <input id="phone" name="car" type="text" class="required">
             </div>
        </section>
       
        <h3>Finish</h3>
        <section>
            <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Probablemente ya hasta lo habías resuelto por tu cuenta. Pero a la mejor esta respuesta le puede servir a alguien más.